# How to "Sum distinct" with DAX formula based on 3 columns? Microsoft PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have been struggling with this for some time and are not able to solve this.
I have three columns in this small test dataset

**order_id**
**code**
***weight*** from which I need the distinct sum

I need to find a way to calculate the *distinct sum* of **weight** for each **code** per **order_id**

[image]

I have tried to use formulas like this one:

```
Total = SUMX(DISTINCT(data[code]); FIRSTNONBLANK(data[weight]; 0))
```

But I do not see any way of adding this *per* **order_id** to the formula.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there. The simplest modification would be to change your measure to this:

```
Total = SUMX(DISTINCT(data); FIRSTNONBLANK(data[weight]; 0))
```

Notice here that the table I'm passing into `SUMX` is the full `data` table rather than just a single column of that table so that `order_id` (and `weight`) is part of determining whether a row is distinct.

If you have other columns and want to only use `order_id` and `code` to determine distinct rows, then instead of `DISTINCT(data)` you could use `SUMMARIZE(data, data[order_id], data[code])`, which groups by the specified columns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like to learn a little more about what's going on here. Can you tell me why the FIRSTNONBLANK() function is required?

Comment: It isn't required.  You could just use `data[weight]` as the second argument of `SUMX` but I left that part of the code alone to focus on the part that I did change.